# Updating the value of a react-final-form Field component with a onSelect function call?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-places-api, semantic-ui-react, react-final-form

I'm doing a react application with typescript and using react-final-form, I'm using some react libraries to integrate the google places and geocoder APIs: *"react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.1"* and *"react-final-form": "^6.3.0"*

The problem I'm having is updating the value in the react-final-form field after the user selects one of the suggestions delivered by the auto complete component on the onSelect: Below are some excerpts of the code:

**onSelect Functions:**

```
const handleCitySelect = (selectedCity: string) => {
    geocodeByAddress(selectedCity)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latlng => {
        setCityLatLng(latlng);
      }); <-- Here I need to update the field with selectedCity
  };

  const handleVenueSelect = (selectedVenue: string) => {
    geocodeByAddress(selectedVenue)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latlng => {
        setVenueLatLng(latlng);
      }); <-- Here I need to update the field with selectedVenue
  };
```

**React final form:**

```
      <FinalForm <-- react-final-form component

        validate={validate}
        initialValues={activity}
        onSubmit={handleFinalFormSubmit}
        render={({ handleSubmit, invalid, pristine }) => (
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} loading={loading}> <-- semantic-ui-react component
            <Field
              name="title"
              placeholder="Title"
              value={activity.title}
              component={TextInput}
            />
            <Field
              name="description"
              placeholder="Description"
              rows={3}
              value={activity.description}
              component={TextAreaInput}
            />
            <Field
              component={SelectInput}
              options={category}
              name="category"
              placeholder="Category"
              value={activity.category}
            />
            <Form.Group widths="equal">
              <Field
                component={DateInput}
                name="date"
                date={true}
                placeholder="Date"
                value={activity.date}
              />
              <Field
                component={DateInput}
                name="time"
                time={true}
                placeholder="Time"
                value={activity.time}
              />
            </Form.Group>

            <Field <-- field I need to update after the onSelect callback
              component={PlaceInput}
              name="city"
              placeholder="City"
              options={{ types: ["(cities)"] }}
              value={activity.city}
              onSelect={handleCitySelect}
            />
            <Field <-- field I need to update after the onSelect callback
              component={PlaceInput}
              name="venue"
              placeholder="Venue"
              options={{
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(cityLatLng),
                radius: 1000,
                types: ["establishment"]
              }}
              value={activity.venue}
              onSelect={handleVenueSelect}
            />
<...>
```

The PlaceInput is a custom component that servers as a wrapper around the PlacesAutocomplete component that does the suggestions according to what the user types.

Thanks to anyone who can suggest a solution. I scoured the Internet and couldn't find a quick fix to something that I feel should be a no-brainer. If more explanations are needed please let me know or more code excerpts.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

To set the field value, your `PlaceInput` needs to call `input.onChange(newValue)`.

Also, you should not be passing a `value` prop to `Field`. [That's only for checkboxes and radio buttons](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps#value).

Comment: Hello Erik, thanks for your reply, but your suggestion is still not very clear to me. I do pass the input.onChange but I'm not sure where should I call that method. Here is a link to the github [link]https://github.com/luisfguzman/Reactivities/blob/master/client-app/src/app/common/form/PlaceInput.tsx if you could check it out. Also you said to not pass a value prop to Field but I'm using this component ActivityForm as for create and edit an Activity, so what is the correct method to initialize the data when user is editing an Activity? Thanks again for your help is greatly appreciated it!

Comment: Hmmm... A sandbox would be really helpful here.

Comment: Hi Erik, I created a sandbox for the client-app which is my react-typescrit front end: [link]https://codesandbox.io/s/github/luisfguzman/Reactivities/tree/master/client-app But it doesn't have the connection to the API which is a DotNetCore application. I have deployed it to azure for the full integration: [link]https://intermingle.azurewebsites.net/ The problem I'm having is when creating/editing and activity the City/Venue fields of the form aren't updated when the user selects one of the suggestions. Let me know if this helps. Thanks again!